# check_jvm Nagios plugin to monitor java threads and heap memory not running

Tags: websphere, nagios, websphere-portal, nagiosxi

I have a Nagios monitoring system to monitor servers. I have a server in which WebSphere portal has been installed. I want to configure a system in which when there is high CPU usage/thread count increases, it automatically takes a thread dump. For this, I am using nagios plugin `check_jvm`. This plugin uses a jar called `JvmInspector.jar`. `JvmInspector.jar` should list all the jvm names which are running in the system.
Usage of `JvmInspector.jar` is as follows:

```
java -jar JvmInspector.jar all
```

When I am running this, it is showing an empty result although I have a running WebSphere portal server running. Inspite of this, I tried to run 'check_jvm' plugin but it shows the following result:

```
[root@dev03 libexec]# sudo -u root /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jvm -n WebSphere_Portal -p threads -w 105 -c 135

UNKNOWN Can't connect to the JVM:
```

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: `java -jar JvmInspector.jar all` show only JVM's for current user. Is your app running under root?

Comment: yes , my ' WebSphere portal ' is running under user 'root'. That's why it is surprising for me why it is not showing the JVMs ??......

Comment: Can you try `bash -x /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_jvm -n WebSphere_Portal -p threads -w 105 -c 135` as root?

Comment: Yes , I tried . But ultimately it also list the same output . Below is some part of the output because the whole stack trace is very large ----

Comment: + PUID=0
+ '[' -z 5431 ']'
+ expr 5431 : '[0-9]\+$'
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ TIMEOUT=
+ timeout --version
+ TIMEOUT='timeout 7'
++ timeout 7 java -jar /usr/local/bin/JvmInspector.jar 5431
+ JVMDATA=
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo ''
+ grep 'class count'
+ p_unknown 'Can'\''t connect to the JVM: '
+ echo 'UNKNOWN Can'\''t connect to the JVM: '
+ exit 3        ........ Here 5431 is the process Id of WebSphere portal .

Comment: I think until JvmInspector.jar works properly & lists the jvm names , 'check_jvm' plugin won't work properly .

Comment: Are you using last version (0.5) of this plugin? Can you upload your trace to Pastebin for analyze?